# python script for run time log seggregation

Tags: python

I have a requirement of reading the log file in run time and segregate them in to multiple different files based on the search.

Since the log file will be rotated on a daily basis I have used "getmtime" to read the latest modified log file and read the lines dynamically as it is updated in the log and segregate them in to multiple files.

However my code fails to read new lines in the log file. Request your inputs here.

```
import time
import os
import glob

newest = max(glob.iglob('/var/log/*.log'), key=os.path.getmtime)

with open(newest,'r') as file, \
open(‘result1.log’, ‘w’) as output_file1, \
open(‘result2.log’, ‘w’) as output_file2, \
open(‘result3.log’, ‘w’) as output_file3:


    while 1:

        where = file.tell()
        line = file.readline()

        if not line:

           time.sleep(1)

           file.seek(where)

        else:

             if “abc” in line:

                 output_file1.write(line)

             if “def” in line:

                 output_file2.write(line)

             if “ghi” in line:

                 output-file3.write(line)

         newest1 = max(glob.iglob('/var/log/*.log'), key=os.path.getmtime)

         if newest1 != newest

             newest= newest1

             file = open(newest, 'r')
```

Thanks & Reagrds,
Ankith

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your code contains syntax errors, so I don't think the code  you presented above is the same as the code you really use, or you would have noticed. I have copy-pasted your sample, fixed both errors and ran it - the results were as you expected, new lines were read correctly. Thus, I believe your problem is not related to this sample.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the swift reply. I agree that there might be syntax error as I copied from notepad.So you mean to say this code is reading new line from log as it is populated?